# UNABLE to add current alert price in tradingview pinescript

Tags: javascript, json, pine-script, tradingview-api, alpine.js

i am unable to find the relevant solution for the price condition [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR71H.png)

```
plotshape(longCondition, title="Buy Signal", text="BUY", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.labelup, size=size.normal, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, transp=0)


alertcondition(longCondition, title="Buy Alert", message="BUY")
```

what i want is that when ever i will get buy signal at that time the whatever the current price is i want to show that current price with  buy label in the chart  that should result something like this [finalresultimage link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIvJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pine script runs when bar is closed. Therefore, the current price when you get when `buy` is triggered is equal to `close`. Keep in mind that as a default, this will not be the price you will enter the position. You will enter a position on the first trade of the next bar (which will be `open` of the next bar).

If you want to add `close` price to each `buy` trigger, just add it to the `text` paramater on `plotshape()` function. Example on v5:

```
text="BUY: " + str.tostring(close)
```